# Typescript: interface gets default value for property

Tags: typescript, angular11

I am writing an event system with different types of events in angular 11
I am defining an enum for the different types of events

```
enum EventTypes {
  Pending,
  Active,
  Complete
}
```

and interfaces for the different events

```
interface PendingEvent { type: EventTypes.Pending }

interface ActiveEvent { type: EventTypes.Active, progress: number }

interface CompleteEvent { type: EventTypes.Complete, data: any }
```

I then define a type to bundle those events

```
type Event = PendingEvent | ActiveEvent | CompleteEvent;
```

But now, every time i create a new event i have to give a type.

```
const event: ActiveEvent = {
  progress: 83
}
```

I get an error saying that i am missing the 'type' property.
I expect the type to be automatically set depending on the event type i create.

Comment: That won't happen. TypeScript isn't going to set values, it doesn't exist at runtime. Once the type is erased by compilation you just have `const event = { progress: 83 }`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is there a way to set the type of different events? So that i cant check 'event.type === EventType.Active' ?

Comment: You have to do runtime work; TS won't emit different code based on its static type system. But you could refactor that runtime work to be done just once... for example,  would [this](https://tsplay.dev/lm0axW) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you use classes you might be able to achieve what you want. You can even keep the interface if you like, or simplify it to one interface.

```
interface EventInterface { type: EventTypes; progress?: number; data?: any}
```

```
class ActiveEvent implements EventInterface {
   constructor (progress: number) {
     this.type =  EventTypes.Active;
     this.progress = progress;
     }
}
```

```
const event = new ActiveEvent(82);
```

Similarly you can make classes for the other two types of Events, which constructors automatically set the type.

Of course, classes and instances of classes aren't the same as typed variables as you have now, but it sounded like this might help your (guessed by me) use case.

Information here may be helpful: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#implementing-an-interface